# Have more than nine members as part of the Google+ Hangout audience

Tags: google-plus

I am doing a talk show with significant crowd turn out where it will be a conversation between three people in three locations over video conference. The rest will be an audience but Google Hangouts specifies a limit of **10 people.**

Is there a way I can do this with a large audience crowd and only three people talking?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at Google Hangouts On Air. You can broadcast a Hangout on YouTube to a virtually unlimited audience.

http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2012/05/google-hangouts-on-air-broadcast-your.html

Comment: I saw this but its just 1 person to a large crowd. In my case the situation is like Conan O Brien interviewing two peeps across the globe and it should be broadcasted.

Comment: I'm confused. A Hangout on Air allows for up to 10 people inside the hangout, plus many more watching via YouTube or via an embedded YouTube player.

How is this not exactly what you want?